# Rails: should I hand off to another controller action for render or redirect?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, controller

Need some answers on Rails best practices. Right now, in my `events_controller.rb` I have the following action (in summary):

```
def create
  ...
  [perform a lot of operations and create a lot of state]
  ...
  if @event.save #successfully creates the record
    if @event.donation_request_flag
      # if the flag is set, redirect to the "new" action in the donation_request_controller
      redirect_to new_donation_request_path 
    else
      # otherwise, just complete the "create" action in events_controller
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js { render 'draw_calendar' }
        format.html { redirect_to show_calendar_path }
      end
    end
```

On the one hand, this seems like the right thing to do: hand off the new donation request to the donation request controller in the most straightforward way. On the other hand, all of the state created here in the events controller (which won't change), now needs to be recreated again (or passed through the redirect to the donation requests controller via URL parameters). And that seems very repetitive.

Is there a way to simply call the donation request controller action from the events controller without the redirect and have that render the result? And is that the "proper" way to do such a thing?